# How to retain state of previous page while navigating back to it from another page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context, react-state-management, mui-datatable

How to retain or preserve state of previous page. I can select some rows and on clicking of Next I am suppose to open another page and when user click on Cancel I have to roll back to previous page with selected rows preserved. I know if I open the below screen as component and overlay it on top of parent that will do my job. I have to manage state within the same parent component instead of creating it as page using react router dom. I was wondering how to do it using react router dom(I mean via pages and not just component). Can anyone suggest me the proper way to handle it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to store your state in local storage.
Let's take a look at an example: https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

If you're using react-router, you can use the `useLocation` hook, and update the local store when the user will change the page:

```
const location = useLocation()
const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("name", "Bob");

useEffect(() => {
  setName(yourState)
}, [location])
```

Comment: I don't think "When the user will change the page" is the time when you'd want to store this. It sounds like this will just save the "current" new page each time, not keep the "previous" location.